# C# BracePos Difficulty?

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin

I'm pulling data into TextBoxes for my App with a Index of '{' and I can't seem to get the last box added (ExampleBox) to input the last bit of data after the last '{' into the correct box, instead it keeps repeating the description box and putting the description text in the Example box as well as the Description box itself.

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace SQLCheatSheetProto
{
    partial class FourthScreenViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public FourthScreenViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            SearchText.ShouldReturn += (sender) => {
                SearchText.ResignFirstResponder();
                LoadCommand(SearchText.Text.ToLower());      //If return is pressed while typing in the search box, this acts as though the user has pressed the physical Search button
                return true;


            };
        }

        public void LoadCommand(string commandName)
        {
            bool commandFound = false;
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("/Users/lcharlton/Documents/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetFiles")) {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (file);
                bool endOfFile = false;
                while (!commandFound && !endOfFile) {
                    string s = reader.ReadLine ();
                    int bracePos = s.IndexOf ("}");
                    if (bracePos >= 0) {
                        if (s.Substring (0, bracePos).ToLower() == commandName) {                              //Searches through every .csv in the specified path and returns the first command that has a command name mathcing what the user specified.

                            s = s.Substring (bracePos + 1);
                            bracePos = s.IndexOf ("}");
                            SyntaxText.Text = s.Substring (0, bracePos);
                            DescriptionText.Text = s.Substring (bracePos + 1);
                            ExampleText.Text = s.Substring (bracePos + 1);

                            DescriptionText.Font = SyntaxText.Font;
                            commandFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (reader.EndOfStream) {
                        reader.Close ();
                        endOfFile = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        partial void SearchClick (UIButton sender)
        {
            try{
                LoadCommand(SearchText.Text.ToLower());}
            catch{}
        }
    }
}
```

That is my SecondViewController
My First is:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using CoreGraphics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SQLCheatSheetProto
{
    partial class SecondScreenViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public SecondScreenViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        string path = "/Users/lcharlton/Documents/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetFiles";    //file path where the .csv files are stored on the machine (Can be replaced with something like  Directory.CurrentFilePath() though you would need to move the .csvs there)

        CGRect screen = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
        List<UIButton> buttons = new List<UIButton>();


        static CGRect scrollerFrame;   //scroller initialization
        static UIScrollView scroller;

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            //scroller.ContentSize.Height = screen.Size.Height;


            scrollerFrame = new CGRect (0, 160, screen.Width, screen.Height - 160);
            scroller = new UIScrollView (scrollerFrame);
            View.AddSubview (scroller);




            View.SendSubviewToBack (scroller); //Scroller is added to the main screen so that buttons can then be added to the scroller



            int buttonHieght = 0;
            int screenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(screen.Width);

            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) 
            {
                string filename = file.Replace (path + "/", "");
                filename = filename.Replace (".csv", "");
                if(filename != ".DS_Store"){
                //add a button
                var btn = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.System);
                    btn.Frame = new CGRect (0, buttonHieght, screenWidth,44);              //Goes to the file path specified and reads all filenames; displaying them as buttons on-screen
                btn.SetTitle (filename, UIControlState.Normal);

                scroller.Add (btn);

                buttons.Add (btn);

                buttonHieght = buttonHieght + 50;

                btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>  //each button generated waits on the event of being tapped and runs this code if that happens
                    {
                    LoadCommands(btn.CurrentTitle);
                    };
                }
                if (buttonHieght >= screen.Height-1000) 
                {
                    CGSize size = new CGSize (0, 45);
                    scroller.ContentSize = scroller.ContentSize + size;                    //Allows the scroll view to adapt it's content size in order to allow scrolling through a list of buttons
                }

            }
        }

        public void LoadCommands(string buttonPressed)
        {
            foreach (UIButton button in buttons)
            {
                //delete all buttons in buttons<>
                button.Hidden = true;
            }

            buttons.Clear ();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (path + "/" + buttonPressed + ".csv");
            bool commandsLoaded = false;
            int buttonHieght = 0;
            int screenWidth = Convert.ToInt32(screen.Width);
            while (!commandsLoaded) 
            {
                var btn = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.System);
                btn.Frame = new CGRect (0, buttonHieght, screenWidth, 44);        //Finds all command names in the .csv selected and generates buttons based on the names. ('}' is used as a delimiter in the .csvs)
                string commandRecord = reader.ReadLine ();
                int bracePos = commandRecord.IndexOf ("}");
                string commandName = commandRecord.Substring (0, bracePos);
                btn.SetTitle (commandName, UIControlState.Normal);

                scroller.Add (btn);
                btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {  //waits for the button to be pressed to run the code
                    DisplayCommand(btn.CurrentTitle, buttonPressed);
                };
                buttons.Add (btn);
                buttonHieght = buttonHieght + 50;
                if (reader.EndOfStream) {
                    commandsLoaded = true;          //when the StreamReader reaches the end of the file, it exits the loop
                    reader.Close ();             
                }

                if (buttonHieght >= screen.Height-1000) 
                {
                    CGSize size = new CGSize (0, 45);          //extends content size of the scroll view in order to add more buttons as needed
                    scroller.ContentSize = scroller.ContentSize + size;
                }
            }
        }

        public void DisplayCommand(string lastButton, string file)
        {
            foreach (UIButton button in buttons) 
            {
                button.Hidden = true;
            }

            bool commandFound = false;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (path + "/" + file + ".csv");
            while (!commandFound) 
            {
                string commandRecord = reader.ReadLine ();
                int bracePos = commandRecord.IndexOf ("}");
                string commandName = commandRecord.Substring (0, bracePos);

                if (commandName == lastButton) 
                {
                    var nameBox = new UITextField();
                    var syntaxBox = new UITextView();
                    var descripBox = new UITextView();
                    var exampleBox = new UITextView ();
                    nameBox.Frame = new CGRect (25,160, screen.Width - 50, 50);      //splits the line of the selected command up into it's separate parts NAME}SYNTAX}DESCRIPTION
                    syntaxBox.Frame = new  CGRect (20, 220, screen.Width - 50, 100);
                    descripBox.Frame = new CGRect (20, 300, screen.Width - 50, 150);
                    exampleBox.Frame = new CGRect (20, 380, screen.Width - 50, 50);

                    nameBox.Text = commandName;

                    commandRecord = commandRecord.Substring (bracePos + 1);

                    bracePos = commandRecord.IndexOf("}");                          //Each separate piece is assigned to the text value of a textview or textfield

                    syntaxBox.Text = commandRecord.Substring (0, bracePos);

                    commandRecord = commandRecord.Substring (bracePos + 1);

                    bracePos = commandRecord.IndexOf("}"); 

                    descripBox.Text = commandRecord;

                    commandRecord = commandRecord.Substring (bracePos + 1);

                    exampleBox.Text = commandRecord;




                    scroller.Hidden = true;

                    View.AddSubview (nameBox);
                    View.AddSubview (syntaxBox);                                  //The text is then added to the viewcontroller, NOT THE SCROLLER.
                    View.AddSubview (descripBox);
                    View.AddSubview (exampleBox);


                    commandFound = true;
                    reader.Close ();
                }

                File.OpenRead("/Users/lcharlton/Documents/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetFiles");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a strong feeling its something to do with the second view controller hence why I put it first, if you could help that'd be great :)

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: Do you need to check text between `{` and `}`? You use everytime `.IndexOf("}");` the other `{` is not checked.

Comment: I only use } as a delimiter within the data as it is manmade data.

Answer (score 0):

You placed the same text in description box and example box:

```
DescriptionText.Text = s.Substring(bracePos + 1);
ExampleText.Text = s.Substring(bracePos + 1);
```

Correct code would be this:

```
    s = s.Substring(bracePos + 1);
    bracePos = s.IndexOf("}");
    SyntaxText.Text = s.Substring(0, bracePos);

    s = s.Substring(bracePos + 1);
    bracePos = s.IndexOf("}");
    DescriptionText.Text = s.Substring(0, bracePos);

    s = s.Substring(bracePos + 1);
    ExampleText.Text = s;
```

**Be sure that brace position is everytime > -1.**

It would be easier to split the string with `}`. Then you have a collection of strings which can be used to fill the textboxes.

```
    public void LoadCommand(string commandName)
    {
        bool commandFound = false;
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles("/Users/lcharlton/Documents/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetProto/SQLCheatSheetFiles"))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
            bool endOfFile = false;
            while (!commandFound && !endOfFile)
            {
                string s = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] items = s.Split(new[] { '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (items.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (items[0].ToLower() == commandName)
                    {                              
                        //Searches through every .csv in the specified path and returns the first command that has a command name mathcing what the user specified.
                        SyntaxText.Text = items.Length > 1 ? items[1] : string.Empty;
                        DescriptionText.Text = items.Length > 2 ? items[2] : string.Empty;
                        ExampleText.Text = items.Length > 3 ? items[3] : string.Empty;

                        DescriptionText.Font = SyntaxText.Font;
                        commandFound = true;
                    }
                }
                if (reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    endOfFile = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```